# Не могу слинковаться из С++ под Windows (x64, MSYS2) с POCO

Tags: c++, windows, компоновщик, poco, msys2

Господа.

я уже неделю занимаюсь этим, перепробовал всё, что только можно, на нескольких компьютерах, но прогресса - пока никакого.

Специально пишу подробно, пожалуйста, проверьте ход моих рассуждений, возможно, я где то "схожу с тропы".

Смотрите, что я делаю.

Система - Windows 10, 64bit, установлены MSYS2, притащивший в систему g++ и gdb, и Visual Studio 2019.

g++ --version выдает инфу `g++ (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 9.2.0`

Всё 64-битное.

Беру проект `https://github.com/spot62/PocoAngularTodo` - простое приложение, которое запускает http - сервер из POCO и начинает слушать порт.

Хочу скомпилировать его для своей системы (из командной строки, потому что потом я эту конфигурацию засуну в VSC и буду в ней дебажиться).

Заглядываю в Makefile, вижу флаги линковщика, которые говорят мне, что на этапе линковки нужны такие библиотеки: `-lPocoFoundation -lPocoNet  -lPocoNetSSL -lPocoUtil -lPocoXML`

Ставлю чистенький, cвеженький vcpkg из репозитория `https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg` и собираю его, запустив bootstrap-vcpkg.bat - это рекомендованный  способ. Пока всё нормально.

Теперь у меня есть пакетный менеджер, могу попросить у него собрать библиотеки. Они мне, для 64битного проекта, нужны 64 битные. Поэтому я собираю их вызовом `vcpkg install poco:x64-windows`

Теперь у меня есть следующее:

include - файлы, котроые лежат в `D:\Programs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include`

Библиотеки, котроые лежат в `D:\Programs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\debug\lib`

Глазами смтотрю - вроде всё на месте.

Делаю из всей вышеприведенной информации команду для g++: включаю туда путь к инклудам, путь к либам (не забыв перевернуть слеши в другую сторону), и список библиотек, с которыми я собственно линкуюсь. Для очистки совести еще раз говорю, что у меня всё 64-битное ключем -m64.

Теперь мне - по моей логике - команда `g++ -m64 -std=c++17 -lstdc++ -ID:\Programs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include -lPocoFoundation -lPocoNet  -lPocoNetSSL -lPocoUtil -lPocoXML -LD:/Programs/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib main.cpp TodoServerApp.cpp -o TodoServerApp`, вызванная из директории проекта, должна всё собрать.

Но нет. Получаю ВСЕГДА, при любых попытках как то повлиять на стуацию, ошибки линковки. В этом кокретном случае - линкер просто не видит библиотек:

`g++ -m64 -std=c++17 -lstdc++ -ID:\Programs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include -lPocoFoundation -lPocoNet  -lPocoNetSSL -lPocoUtil -lPocoXML -LD:/Programs/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib main.cpp TodoServerApp.cpp -o TodoServerApp
In file included from D:\Programs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include/Poco/String.h:22,
                 from D:\Programs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include/Poco/Net/NameValueCollection.h:22,
                 from D:\Programs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include/Poco/Net/MessageHeader.h:22,
                 from D:\Programs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include/Poco/Net/HTTPMessage.h:22,
                 from D:\Programs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include/Poco/Net/HTTPRequest.h:22,
                 from D:\Programs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include/Poco/Net/HTTPServerRequest.h:22,
                 from TodoServerApp.h:4,
                 from TodoServerApp.cpp:4:
D:\Programs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include/Poco/Ascii.h:133:13: warning: 'static bool Poco::Ascii::isAscii(int)' redeclared without dllimport attribute after being referenced with dll linkage
  133 | inline bool Ascii::isAscii(int ch)
      |             ^~~~~
In file included from D:\Programs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include/Poco/Net/HTTPResponse.h:24,
                 from D:\Programs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include/Poco/Net/HTTPServerResponse.h:22,
                 from TodoServerApp.h:6,
                 from TodoServerApp.cpp:4:
D:\Programs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include/Poco/Timestamp.h:256:28: warning: 'static Poco::Timestamp::TimeDiff Poco::Timestamp::resolution()' redeclared without dllimport attribute after being referenced with dll linkage
  256 | inline Timestamp::TimeDiff Timestamp::resolution()
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~
C:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lPocoFoundation
C:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lPocoNet
C:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lPocoNetSSL
C:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lPocoUtil
C:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lPocoXML
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Что еще я пробовал:

0) До объектных файллов процесс доходит без ошибок, я получаю командой `g++ -m64 -std=c++17 -lstdc++ -ID:\Programs\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include -lPocoFoundation -lPocoNet  -lPocoNetSSL -lPocoUtil -lPocoXML -LD:/Programs/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib main.cpp TodoServerApp.cpp -c` хорошие, жирные TodoServerApp.o и main.o

1) пробовал собрать библиотеки при помощи команды
`vcpkg install poco: x64-mingw` - но это так называемый 'community triplets', про который пишут, что он не гарантировано работоспособен - и действительно, он не завершает работу. Повисает где то в середине. я конечно послал логи в составе iisues для vcpkg, но не думаю, что они будут этим особо заниматься.

2) попробовал принудительно выставить статическую линковку. результат примерно такой же.

3) я уже начинаю впадать в паранойю, и думать, не может ли ошибка быть связана с тем, что у меня вызывается линкер "не той системы"? например, 32-битный? Но как это проверить? Вторая параноидальная идея - не может проблем быть из аз того, что компилятор установлен на диск C:\, а проекты и библиотеки лежат на диске D:?

Может быть, есть какой то простой метод диагностики, который мне не приходит в голову и который покажет, что не так с библиотеками? Может, я в силу своей неопытности, просто неправильно формирую команду на линковку с ними?

Спасибо заранее за советы.

Comment: 1) кажется вы путаете Visual Studio и Visual Studio code 2) чтобы прилинковать библиотеку poсo к исполняемому файлу g++ / mingw ее надо сначала надо самостоятельно собрать с использованием этого же компилятора, и с использованием совместимых настроек (т.е. тот же стандарт, выравнивание и т.п.) 3) "я собираю их вызовом vcpkg install" вы ничего не собираете, а копируете готовые бинарики для использования с vc++

Comment: Спасибо, я уже - проворачивая в голове всё, что я делаю - дошел до истины, что и программа и библиотеки должны быть собраны одним и тем же тулчейном. И, скорее всего, vcpkg делает всё припомощи ms- компилятора. Но - он именно СОБИРАЕТ их, а не копирует (как делает какой нибудь conan). И - нет, я не путаю VS c VSC. Под VS всё работает и взлетает со свистом, но среда разработки - тяжеловата, и я как раз жочу пересесть под VSC. А для этого надо научиться под ней - то есть, коротко говоря, из команднйо строки - проект собирать. Сейчас пытаюсь понять, как собрать POCO под винду при помощи g++

Comment: VSC тяжелее, это же браузер, но если под ней и собирать, то зачем обязательно использовать msys и g++? собирайте используя тулчейн VS / msbuild

Comment: А есть пример конфигурации VSC, в которой прописаны микрософтовский компилятор и отладкчик? Можно такой пример привести? Возможно, это действительно выход из положения

Comment: Похоже, попытка под Windows собирать poco при помощи g++ - это путь в никуда. Применить conan я не могу - он ругается что "Case insensitive filesystem can't manage this". То есть, если у тебя Винда - сиди под VS (не VSC) и не рыпайся.

Comment: Проверил - poco есть в пакетах msys2. Не нужно его собирать, достаточно поставить пакет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Господа, большое спасибо, замечание ***HolyBlackCat*** было решающим.

Благодаря ему я вышел на  дискуссию [дискуссию](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637797/compile-poco-with-mingw-on-windowshttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637797/compile-poco-with-mingw-on-windows).

После этого я смог набрать пару команд:

первая  `pacman -Ss poco` нашла пакеты, на её основе я сделал вторую - `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-poco` - и она поставила пакеты в систему.

Но это была еще не окончательная победа. Поискав нужные файлы среди скачанных, я нашел две версии библиотеки: libPocoFoundation.dll.a и PocoFoundationd.dll

После этого, попробовав команду 
`g++ -m64 -std=c++17 -lstdc++ -IC:\Programs\msys64\mingw64\include -lPocoFoundation -lPocoNet  -lPocoNetSSL -lPocoUtil -lPocoXML -LC:/Programs/msys64/mingw64/bin main.cpp TodoServerApp.cpp -o TodoServerApp` - я, наконец, получил нужный результат!

Выводы:

1) Нельзя в одном проекте C++ совмещать код, собранный разными компиляторами

2) "учите матчасть": если бы я сразу знал, что poco есть в msys2 - мне бы пришлось гораздо меньше возиться.

Спасибо большое всем и HolyBlackCat в особенности!

И, пока "суп не остыл в горшке", еще один вопрос: а как быть со статической линковкой? я так понял, что для этого нужно не просто добавить ключ -static в команду сборки проекта, а еще и запастись статическими версиями библиотек.

Я попробовал вариант с тем, что *возможно* в директории msys2 лежит в `msys64\mingw64\bin` динамический вариант, а в `msys64\mingw64\lib` - статический, но так не работает... При попытке линковаться статически по прежнему появляется ошибка линкера о том, что не найдена библиотека. Какие нибудь советы на эту тему есть?

Comment: *"как быть со статической линковкой"* MinGW не умеет линковаться напрямую с .dll (как минимум старый, вроде с какой-то версии он научился это делать, но в любом случае это обычно не нужно). Флажком `-l<...>` обычно подключается либо `lib<...>.a` - статический вариант библиотеки, либо `lib<...>.dll.a` - заглушка, которая загружает .dll при запуске программы. Если есть обе, то линкер использует вторую, если нет флажка `-static`. Соответственно, если файлик `libPocoFoundation.a` (и другие) существует, то статическая линковка возможна (с помощью `-static`).

Comment: *"При попытке линковаться статически по прежнему появляется ошибка линкера"* Если poco использует какие-то другие библиотеки, то при статической линковке их нужно также явно линковать. Попробуйте дернуть `pkg-config`, он должен знать флажки для статической линковки poco (вместе с флажками для всех ее зависимостей).